# How to change Watch function value in vue js as Dynamic?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change watch function value as dynamic when `setKeywords()` method is triggered. So how can I change value?

```js
data() {
    return {
        keywords:null,
        productSearch:null,
    }
},

//This is method i created. When this method is triggered, the watch function called productSearch(val) must like productSearch(this.keywords)
methods: {
    setKeywords(){
        this.keywords='test';
    }
},

// I want to set val = this.keywords when setKeywords method is triggered.
watch: {
    productSearch(val){ 
        fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q="+val)
        .then(response => response.json())              
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `productSearch`? Theres no `productSearch` in your `data`

Comment: I guess you want to trigger productSearch, when keywords is changed? just call the function in setKeywords?

Comment: @null ,I am sorry i forget to mention.can you help me now ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `watch` handler for keywords instead

```
methods:{
    setKeywords(){
        this.keywords='test';
    }, 
    productSearch(val){ 
        fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q="+val)
        .then(response => response.json())
                        
    }
},
 watch: {
    keywords(newVal, oldVal){ 
        if(newVal !== oldVal) this.productSearch(newVal);                   
    }
}
```

For more simplicity, if you are triggering the `setKeywords()` then no need of watch, you can directly call the productSearch inside that handler

```
methods:{
    setKeywords(){ // Note: this must be a dynamic handler to set new values to `keywords`
        this.keywords='test';
        this.productSearch(this.keywords);
    }, 
    productSearch(val){ 
        fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q="+val)
        .then(response => response.json())
                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize your API call in one method:

```
methods: {
  search(search, keywords) {
    productSearch(val){ 
        fetch("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=" + search)
        .then(response => response.json())
  },
  watch: {
     keywords(val) {
       this.search(this.productSearch, val);
     },
     productSearch(val) {
       this.search(val, this.keywords);
     }
  }
}
```